# How can I search and replace line spacing for an entire document?

Tags: microsoft-word, libreoffice-writer, line-spacing

Replacing line spacing formatting in a paragraph is easy, in either Microsoft Word or Libre Office Writer. But how to do it for an entire document? I have alternating paragraphs that are in English and Spanish. The Spanish are already single-spaced, but I want to change all the English to single-spaced, too (they are now set to "At least 0.23").

Here is how the doc looks, with the second English paragraph changed to the single-spacing that I want:

[image]

...and here is the setting for the English paragraphs:

[image]

By selecting Format > Paragraph, I can change a paragraph at a time, but how to do it for the entire document?

Comment: What if you press CTRL-A to select everything, and then make the change?

Comment: Have you applied a separate paragraph style to the Spanish and English paragraphs? Or has everything been styled through overrides of the built-in styles? Does Word (or Libre Office) correctly identify the language that's used in each paragraph?

Comment: @LPChip: That would also change the "special" pages, such as the title page, etc. I ended up just scrolling through and selecting the hundreds of pages after those.

Comment: If the title pages are not that much compared to all the paragraphs, editing all, then going through the few pages that you didn't want, is probably faster.

Answer (score 1):

In MS Office:

Press Ctrl-H to open Find and Replace window. Then press "More" button:

[image]

When your caret is inside "Find what" field, choose Format, and then Paragraph.

[image]

Choose paragraph spacing which you want to replace.

Then repeat all these steps in "Replace with" field.

After that, press "Replace All" button.

---

As I know, the same could be easily done in LibreOffice.